# Select closest element between 2 numpy arrays of differing sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays of different sizes. One of them 'a' contains int values, while the other (larger) np array 'b' contains float values with (say) 3-4 values per element/value in 'a'.

```
a = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 100, size = (7))

a
# array([35, 11, 48, 20, 13, 31, 49])

b = np.array([34.78, 34.8, 35.1, 34.99, 11.3, 10.7, 11.289, 18.78, 19.1, 20.05, 12.32, 12.87, 13.5, 31.03, 31.15, 29.87, 48.1, 48.5, 49.2])

a.shape, b.shape
# ((7,), (19,))
```

The idea is to find the value in 'b' matching each unique value in 'a' in terms of closest distance, which I am computing using abs values. To do it using a single element of 'a', or using the first element of 'a':

```
# Compare first element of a with all elements of b-
np.abs(a[0] - b).argsort()
'''
array([ 3,  2,  1,  0, 14, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18,  9,  8,  7, 12, 11, 10,  4,
        6,  5])
'''

# b[3]
# 34.99

# np.abs(a[0] - b).argsort()[0]
# 3

b[np.abs(a[0] - b).argsort()[0]]
# 34.99
```

So, the 4th element in 'b' (b[3]) is the closest match to a[0].

To compute this for all values in 'a', I use a loop as:

```
for e in a:
    idx = np.abs(e - b).argsort()
    print(f"{e} has nearest match = {b[idx[0]]:.4f}")
'''
35 has nearest match = 34.9900
11 has nearest match = 11.2890
48 has nearest match = 48.1000
20 has nearest match = 20.0500
13 has nearest match = 12.8700
31 has nearest match = 31.0300
49 has nearest match = 49.2000
'''
```

How can I achieve this without the slow for loop?

**Note: a.shape = 1400 and b.shape = 1.5 million (approxmately)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **a lot** of values to check you could also try using a [`kdTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree). For few values the overhead of building the tree won't make this worth it, but for large n and especially for searching for nearest neighbors in a multidimensional space it's a lot quicker than computing the distance for all pairs:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

a = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 100, size = (7))

b = np.array([34.78, 34.8, 35.1, 34.99, 11.3, 10.7, 11.289, 18.78, 19.1, 20.05, 12.32, 12.87, 13.5, 31.03, 31.15, 29.87, 48.1, 48.5, 49.2])

kd_tree = spatial.KDTree(np.expand_dims(b, 1))
# This returns distance to the nearest neighbor d
# and position of the nearest neighbor i
d,i = kd_tree.query(np.expand_dims(a, 1), k=[1])
```

Comment: Just to be clear, if I do ```b[i]```, I would get the first nearest neighbor in 'b', since I am using b to construct my KD-Tree data structure, and 'a' is the array which is used to query. What about doing it the other way?

Comment: Doing it the other way you would construct the kd-tree the other way. Building the kd-tree with a and querying with b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting to compute the absolute difference of all pairs, and [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to get the index of the minimal value  (that has `O(n)` complexity while sorting is `O(n*logn)`) per row:

```
out = b[np.argmin(abs(a[:,None]-b), axis=1)]
```

Output: `array([34.99 , 11.289, 48.1  , 20.05 , 12.87 , 31.03 , 49.2  ])`

Be aware that all combinations of the two arrays will be computed at onces, the intermediate will have a size of `len(a) * len(b)`, make sure you have enough memory of `a` and `b` are large.

Intermediate `abs(a[:,None]-b)` (rounded to 1 decimal for nicer display). The rows are corresponding to the elements of `a` and the columns to those of `b`:

```
array([[ 0.2,  0.2,  0.1,  0. , 23.7, 24.3, 23.7, 16.2, 15.9, 15. , 22.7,
        22.1, 21.5,  4. ,  3.9,  5.1, 13.1, 13.5, 14.2],
       [23.8, 23.8, 24.1, 24. ,  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  7.8,  8.1,  9. ,  1.3,
         1.9,  2.5, 20. , 20.2, 18.9, 37.1, 37.5, 38.2],
       [13.2, 13.2, 12.9, 13. , 36.7, 37.3, 36.7, 29.2, 28.9, 28. , 35.7,
        35.1, 34.5, 17. , 16.8, 18.1,  0.1,  0.5,  1.2],
       [14.8, 14.8, 15.1, 15. ,  8.7,  9.3,  8.7,  1.2,  0.9,  0.1,  7.7,
         7.1,  6.5, 11. , 11.1,  9.9, 28.1, 28.5, 29.2],
       [21.8, 21.8, 22.1, 22. ,  1.7,  2.3,  1.7,  5.8,  6.1,  7. ,  0.7,
         0.1,  0.5, 18. , 18.2, 16.9, 35.1, 35.5, 36.2],
       [ 3.8,  3.8,  4.1,  4. , 19.7, 20.3, 19.7, 12.2, 11.9, 11. , 18.7,
        18.1, 17.5,  0. ,  0.1,  1.1, 17.1, 17.5, 18.2],
       [14.2, 14.2, 13.9, 14. , 37.7, 38.3, 37.7, 30.2, 29.9, 29. , 36.7,
        36.1, 35.5, 18. , 17.8, 19.1,  0.9,  0.5,  0.2]])
```

Intermediate `np.argmin(abs(a[:,None]-b), axis=1)` that will be used to index `b`:

```
array([ 3,  6, 16,  9, 11, 13, 18])
```

Comment: It seems that my Python program crashes. The intermediate has a size of (1400, 1.5 mn)! Any workaround for this?

Comment: @Arun yes, you can use a KD-Tree as suggested by JonasV, this is an efficient approach when you have large datasets. I answered with broadcasting as your original question requested how to do the same as your code without loop .

Answer (score 1):

```
b[np.argmin(abs(a[:, None] - b[None, :]), axis=1)]
```

Let's break it down:

- `a[:, None] - b[None, :]` expand `a` and `b` in two different directions. This makes the difference of all elements of `a` with all the elements of `b` and stores them into a 2D array of size `len(a) * len(b)`. This is the part that replaces the `for` loop
- `np.argmin(..., axis=1)` selects for each row the minimum of the values. Each value is in `range(0, len(b))`
- `b[...]` then selects the value